# In R, how do I produce a data frame with rownames of every unique rowname of multiple input data frames, with nonexistent values input as 0 or NULL?

Tags: r, dataframe, vegan

I have a series of data frames containing plant species names and associated percent covers from multiple quadrats and would like to streamline the task of generating a single data frame in which all species recorded in *any* quadrat are represented as columns and in which each row corresponds to a single quadrat. Currently, quadrat-specific data frames contain columns only for the species which were found to be present. I would like to integrate all quadrat-specific data frames into a single data frame in which absence of a species at a quadrat is denoted by FALSE or zero.

Objects `a` and `b` are dummy objects showing the format of my data, where a and b represent distinct quadrats. Object `df` shows the format of my objective, although it is here generated manually. "abund" represents abundance, and associated numbers are percent cover values. Objects `spA` through `spI` represent nine dummy plant species names, of which five are present in quadrat a and seven are present in quadrat b.

```
> a.names <- c("spA","spB","spC","spD","spE")
> a <- t(data.frame(c(40,20,10,10,10), row.names = a.names))
> row.names(a) <- "a.abund" 
> a
        spA spB spC spD spE
a.abund  40  20  10  10  10
> 
> b.names <- c("spC","spD","spE","spF","spG","spH","spI")
> b <- t(data.frame(c(40,10,10,10,10,10,10), row.names = b.names))
> row.names(b) <- "b.abund"
> b
        spC spD spE spF spG spH spI
b.abund  40  10  10  10  10  10  10
> 
> df.names <- c("spA","spB","spC","spD","spE","spF","spG","spH","spI")
> a.abund <- c(40,20,10,10,10,0,0,0,0)
> b.abund <- c(0,0,40,10,10,10,10,10,10)
> ( df <- t(data.frame(a.abund, b.abund, row.names = df.names)) )
        spA spB spC spD spE spF spG spH spI
a.abund  40  20  10  10  10   0   0   0   0
b.abund   0   0  40  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

Comment: This is not entirely clear. You mention `data.frame`s but your sample data are actually `matrix` objects. Can you please clarify. This will determine the best approach.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I did not realize that function `t()` converted the data frames generated above into matrices. There should be a step (as k3b shows below) converting `a` and `b` to data frames after transposition.

Answer (score 3):

If we convert the matrices to `data.frame` first, we can use `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package:

```
a.names <- c("spA","spB","spC","spD","spE")
a <- t(data.frame(c(40,20,10,10,10), row.names = a.names))
row.names(a) <- "a.abund"
a

b.names <- c("spC","spD","spE","spF","spG","spH","spI")
b <- t(data.frame(c(40,10,10,10,10,10,10), row.names = b.names))
row.names(b) <- "b.abund"
b

a <- as.data.frame(a)
b <- as.data.frame(b)

df <- rbindlist(list(a, b), fill = TRUE)

df

> df
   spA spB spC spD spE spF spG spH spI
1:  40  20  10  10  10  NA  NA  NA  NA
2:  NA  NA  40  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

Comment: This works. To anybody (like me) who was confused about why a and b needed to be converted from matrices to data frames - the transpose function appears to convert data frames into matrices.

Comment: Yeah, the two lines converting `a` and `b` won't be needed if the original data is just data frames or data tables.

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
nms <- union(colnames(a) , colnames(b))
ans <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = length(nms))
colnames(ans) <- nms

d <- list(a,b)
for( i in 1:2){
    ans[i , match(colnames(d[[i]]) , colnames(ans))] <- d[[i]]
}
```

- output

```
> ans
     spA spB spC spD spE spF spG spH spI
[1,]  40  20  10  10  10   0   0   0   0
[2,]   0   0  40  10  10  10  10  10  10
```